# Use Open Mapping Theorem to prove reverse norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working through problems in Conway studying for an exam, and I have become stumped on one.  The problem is in the section on Open Mapping Theorem (OMT) and Closed Graph Theorem (CGT).

III.13.6: Let $X$ be compact and suppose that $\mathscr{X}$ is a Banach subspace of $C(X)$.  If $E$ is a closed [hence compact] subset of $X$ such that for every $g \in C(E)$ there is an $f\in \mathscr{X}$ with $f_E = g$, show that there is a constant $c > 0$ such that for each $g \in C(E)$ there is an $f \in \mathscr{X}$ with $f_E$ and $\max\{|f(x)| : x \in X\} \leq c \max\{|g(x)| : x \in E\}$.

My current solution: Of course the final statement is equivalent to stating that $\|f\|_{L^\infty(C(X))} \leq c \|g\|_{L^\infty(C(E))}$. I note that $A : \mathscr{X} \to C(E)$ via $Af = f|_E$ is a bounded linear operator (in fact $\|A\| \leq 1$).  Since we have the precondition that for every $g \in C(E)$ we can find an $f \in \mathscr{X}$ such that $Af = g$, then $A$ is a surjective map.  So the OMT applies.  Note that $\|Af\| = \|f|_E\|_{L^\infty(C(E))}$, so we really want to show that $1/c\|Af\| \geq \|f\|$.  In the previous problem in the book, we in fact have that this holds if and only if $\text{ran}(A)$ is closed and $\text{ker}(A) = \{0\}$ (we needed the OMT, in fact the inverse mapping theorem, to prove the backwards direction).  Now the first condition most certainly holds because a subset of a Banach space is Banach if and only if it is closed and we have surjectivity, but the second I suspect is not necessarily true.

My question: is there a way I can adjust $A$ so as to make it injective, am I missing something, or should I be going about this in a different manner? Thanks.

Comment: I might be missing something but consider $X = [0,1]$, $E = \left[0, \frac12\right]$ and $\mathscr{X} = C[0,1]$. Every $f \in C\left[0, \frac12\right]$ can be extended to a function in $C[0,1]$ but $\|\cdot\|_{\infty, [0,1]}$ is not dominated by a constant times $\|\cdot\|_{\infty, \left[0,\frac12\right]}$.

Comment: Look at $\hat{A}:C(X)/Ker(A)\to C(E)$. It is onto, continuous, and injective. The open mapping theorem gives you that the inverse is bounded. Now, the finiteness of the norm of the inverse gives you $\inf_{m\in Ker(A)}\|f+m\|\leq \|\hat{A}^{-1}\|\|f|_{E}\|$. So, you can take $c$ to be $> \|\hat{A}^{-1}\|$, and since the infimum before is strictly smaller you can pick an $m$ such that the inequality holds.

Comment: @mechanodroid "there is an $f \in \mathscr{X}$ ..."

Comment: @cactus Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: @mechanodroid The conclusion is that there is a $c$ such that for every $g$ there is **an** extension $f$ such that the norm of that particular extension is dominated by the norm of $g$ times $c$.

Comment: @cactus Ah right, thanks.

Comment: I don't usually think about modding out by the kernel, so thank you! That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Well, you were missing injectivity. That is what factoring out the kernel does, ignores the lack of injectivity. The payback is that the inequality that we get is only for the infimum of the norms of the elements of the equivalence class (which is the norm in the quotient).

Comment: Right, which explains why the question is worded as it is.

Comment: This idea of factoring out by the kernel isn't an uncommon one. Essentially, what is being used here is often called the canonical factorisation of the operator. It allows you to pass some kinds of problems about bounded linear operators to problems about bounded linear operators that are bijective which is often helpful.